# JSON Rendering key data not found

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"{\"nodeName\":\"abc\"}":[{"url":"abc","status":true},{"url":"abc","status":true}],"      {\"nodeName\":\"pqr\"}":[{"url":"abc","status":true},{"url":"abc","status":true}]}
```

i am able to get the value(v) using below query code but not able to get key(k). On alert i am getting (undefined abc true). value of k is undefined.

```
 $.each(obj, function() {
      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    alert(k.nodeName +" "+ v.url +" "+v.status);
     });
    });
```

I need value of (k) for further validation. I've validated the JSON string to make sure it was valid, so what am I missing here or is there any other way of doing this?? Please help...

Also, From server end i am passing json object like this:

```
json.put(js.toString(),jsarray)
```

where

```
json = json OBject,
js = json Object,
jsarray = json Array.
```

Comment: Keys are always string. In this case it looks like the key contains JSON itself. You have to parse the JSON into an object first. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196. But honestly, this is a very confusing data structure. It would be better to use the node name directly as key, i.e. your JSON would look like `{"abc": [...], "pgr": [...], ...}`.

Comment: I have changed the json string as below:

{"abc":[{"url":"asd","status":true},{"url":"as","status":true}],"xyz":[{"url":"as","status":false},{"url":"as","status":true}]}

but i need the name of key as abc,xyz but while iterating it is giving as 0 ,1

Comment: Have a look at my answer. In the inner `$.each` you iterating over the value, i.e. the array. The key you want to have is from the outer `$.each` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys are always string. In this case it looks like the key contains JSON itself. You have to parse the JSON into an object first. See [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196).

But honestly, this is a very confusing data structure. It would be better to use the node name directly as key, i.e. your JSON would look like `{"abc": [...], "pgr": [...], ...}`.

Then you would access the data like so:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, arr) {
    $.each(arr, function(_, v) {
        alert(key +" "+ v.url +" "+v.status);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @Felix Kling.... it worked for me. i was looking for this solution since last 2 days. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome! When you get an answer that solves your problem, please click on the checkmark next to it to "accept" it (you can always only accept one answer). This also signals others that this question is solved.

Comment: this solution worked for me. i am able to get the value in alert but when i am trying to set the value in jstl:set, it is not working.

but key is getting set in jstl:set

Comment: I don't know what `jstl:set` is so I cannot really help you there. Sorry.

Comment: np, but can u please tell me how to convert the values of json array(v.url and v.status) in to javascript string ???

Comment: First of all, `v` is not a "JSON array" it is a JavaScript object. At the moment you are accessing the data, you don't have JSON anymore. The JSON was already parsed into arrays and objects. `v.url` and `v.status` are already strings.